# Access local website from IE virtual machine using OSX squidman app

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, virtual-machine, squid

I am using the [squidman app](http://squidman.net/squidman/index.html) in my macbook to access my local site (ej. *my-site.dev*) from mobile devices, until this point, everything is fine (I get this done by following [this tutorial](http://egalo.com/2012/05/29/testing-mac-web-site-using-local-hostname-on-mobile-device/)). But now I'm trying to access the same website from an IE10 virtual machine installed on my macbook, on the virtual machine I went to *Internet Options / Connections / LAN Settings* there I checked the *Use a proxy server for your LAN* and added my macbook IP on the *address* field, then I filled the *port* field with the same port as the configured with squidman (8080), and when I go to any website I get this error:

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: my-site.dev
Access Denied.

Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.
```

This is the template that squidman generates:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# WARNING - do not edit this template unless you know what you are doing
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# the parent cache
cache_peer %PARENTPROXY% parent %PARENTPORT% 7 no-query no-digest no-netdb-exchange default


# disk and memory cache settings
cache_dir ufs %CACHEDIR% %CACHESIZE% 16 256
maximum_object_size %MAXOBJECTSIZE%


# store coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir %CACHEDIR%


# the hostname squid displays in error messages
visible_hostname %VISIBLEHOSTNAME%


# log & process ID file details
cache_access_log stdio:%ACCESSLOG%
cache_store_log stdio:%STORELOG%
cache_log %CACHELOG%
pid_filename %PIDFILE%


# Squid listening port
http_port %PORT%


# Access Control lists
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
%ALLOWEDHOSTS%
%DIRECTHOSTS%


# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager 
http_access deny manager


# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports


# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports


# protect web apps running on the proxy host from external users
# http_access deny to_localhost


# rules for client access go here
http_access allow localhost
%HTTPACCESSALLOWED%


# after allowed hosts, deny all other access to this proxy
# don't list any other access settings below this point
http_access deny all


# specify which hosts have direct access (bypassing the parent proxy)
%ALWAYSDIRECT%
always_direct deny all


# hierarchy stop list (squid-recommended)
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?



# refresh patterns (squid-recommended)
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

# hosts file
hosts_file /private/etc/hosts
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by going to *preferences / clients / Provide proxy servers for* in the squidman app and adding there the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet. Now I can open my site both in the device and the IE10 virtual machine.